# What is the best way to write unit-tests in Dart?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

Dart doesn't seem to have a dedicated unit-testing framework yet. What is the best approach to write and run unit-tests?

There are some very low-level examples in Dart source code (e.g. \tests\corelib\src\ListTest.dart), like this:

```dart
class ListTest {

  static testMain() {
    testList();
    testExpandableList();
  }

  static void testList() { ... }
  static void testExpandableList() { ... }
}

main() {
  ListTest.testMain();
}
```

Is this the recommended way to write tests in Dart, or is there any effort to make it easier with some unit-testing library, like x-unit?

Is there an easy way how to run all unit-tests written in this way and see results?

Comment: Since the unittest package is now available, could you change the accepted answer to Antony's below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unit-testing in Dart is still very much under development. We (the Dart authors) currently use a python script (tools/test.py) to execute all our tests. The script runs through predefined directories, looks for files ending with 'Test', executes them, and compares them to the expected outcome.

Several days ago, a first version of test.dart (the equivalent in Dart) has been submitted. In the near future we will switch from tools/test.py to tools/test.dart to execute all our tests.

If you are writing a big project you could reuse our testing-framework. We are using it on a daily basis and it is pretty stable. For smaller projects the time spent on learning the framework might not be worth the effort. I would furthermore not be surprised if there are (or will be) other testing-frameworks.

The ListTest from your question has been written very early, when top-level functions were not yet available. It has since been modified (adding the main function) but we wouldn't write the test in this way anymore. Unless needed, we don't create classes in our test-cases. See, for example, [here](http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/frog/tests/leg/src/LinkTest.dart?spec=svn2280&r=1560) for a more recent test.

Edit: There is also a unit-test framework in client/testing/unittest/. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/tests/client/json/json_tests.dart?spec=svn2304&r=1437) for a test using this framework. This one also has the advantage that it runs in the browser.

Comment: I'll just add that unittest also supports running in the standalone VM and on top of frog/node now too.

Comment: this answer is a little dated now. there is a unittest library in the tip of trunk now.

Answer (score 7):

[dartlang.org](http://www.dartlang.org/) has a very long article about the [current state of unit testing in dart](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/). API documentation can be found [here](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/unittest/0.11.0+5/index.html#unittest/unittest).

```dart
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

void main() {
  test('QuickSort', () =>
    expect(QuickSort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]),
      orderedEquals([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
  );
}

int _Partition(List array, int left, int right, int pivotIndex) {
  var pivotValue = array[pivotIndex];
  array[pivotIndex] = array[right];
  array[right] = pivotValue;
  var storeIndex = left;
  for (var i = left; i < right; i++) {
    if (array[i] < pivotValue) {
      var tmp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[storeIndex];
      array[storeIndex] = tmp;
    }
  }
  var tmp = array[storeIndex];
  array[storeIndex] = array[right];
  array[right] = tmp;
  return storeIndex;
}

void _QuickSort(List array, int left, int right) {
  if (left < right) {
    int pivotIndex = left + ((right-left) / 2);
    pivotIndex = _Partition(array, left, right, pivotIndex);
    _QuickSort(array, left, pivotIndex-1);
    _QuickSort(array, pivotIndex+1, right);
  }
}

List QuickSort(List array) {
  _QuickSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[This post](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1A3O34aghr44umPA7fc9YGvFAHTYQFVCCRjcLCM6Yaw8) from "Adam Coding" (via G+) gives a very detailed description of the current state of dart unit testing, with nice screenshots of the In-Browser view of your unit tests.

Answer (score 4):

Use the **test** Dart package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test

This package was previously named [unittest](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/unittest) which is now deprecated, but you might come across old articles about it. New tests should be written for the "test" package.

The tests can be run manually (like any other Dart program), or using by `pub` (which can run individual tests or multiple tests found under a directory).

Answer (score 1):

There's an example of one approach, DartUnit, on YouTube: [TDD for FizzBuzz in Dart](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-f6bj-Z59h0)

The code's on [GitHub](https://github.com/masaru-b-cl/DartUnit).

Answer (score 1):

A blog about TDD in Dart:
http://tdd-dart.blogspot.com/